# Avoid dupe hammer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

I have [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) in gold. I am not a PHP expert. I would like to *suggest* duplicates using the close dialog but not dupe hammer it.

How can I do this?

Comment: By not casting a duplicate close vote.

Comment: Post the link in the comments. If OP confirms it's indeed a dupe - hammer it. If other users instead are more certain than you that it's the correct dupe - they can vote for it.

Comment: I would argue that if you aren't confident enough to close it unilaterally, you probably shouldn't be voting to close it even as a normal user. If you just want to *suggest* a duplicate, then use a comment as mentioned.